# Why this Hibernate mapping is inserting all the relationship except this "second level" Many To Many relationship?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am working on a Spring Boot project using Spring Data JPA and I am finding the following problem trying to correctly map some pre-existing database tables on entity classes.

In particualr I am finding some difficulties trying to map a specific **Many To Many** relationship (It is strange because I was able to do a similar mapping in the same example).

My DB tables are something like this:

[image]

**NOTE:** the  **user_type** and **operation** tables are typological and contains fixed values.

My problem is that the **Many To Many** relationship between **UserType** and **Operation** table is not working on my code.

Following my classes (the table's name are slightly different on the DB):

1. **User**: it represents a user on a portal:

   @Entity
   @Table(name = "portal_user")
   @Getter
   @Setter
   public class User implements Serializable {

   ```
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5062673109048808267L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "middle_name")
    private String middleName;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "sex")
    private char sex;

    @Column(name = "birthdate")
    private Date birthdate;

    @Column(name = "tex_code")
    private String taxCode;

    @Column(name = "e_mail")
    private String eMail;

    @Column(name = "contact_number")
    private String contactNumber;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Address> addressesList = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(
        name = "portal_user_user_type", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "portal_user_id_fk") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_type_id_fk") }
    )
    Set<UserType> userTypes;



    public User(String firstName, String middleName, String surname, char sex, Date birthdate, String taxCode,
            String eMail, String contactNumber, Date createdAt) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.middleName = middleName;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
        this.taxCode = taxCode;
        this.eMail = eMail;
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }
   ```

   }

**NOTE:** It contains this **Many To Many** relationship between the **portal_user** table (mapped by **User**) and the ** user_type** table (mapped by **UserType). It works fine, the problem is not here.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinTable(
    name = "portal_user_user_type", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "portal_user_id_fk") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_type_id_fk") }
)
Set<UserType> userTypes;
```

2. **Address**: an user can have multiple addesses:

   @Entity
   @Table(name = "address")
   @Getter
   @Setter
   @NoArgsConstructor
   @AllArgsConstructor
   public class Address implements Serializable {

   ```
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6956974379644960088L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "country")
    private String country;

    @Column(name = "province")
    private String province;

    @Column(name = "zip_code")
    private String zipCode;

    @Column(name = "street")
    private String street;

    @Column(name = "notes")
    private String notes;


    @ManyToOne
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude          // Needed by Lombock in "Many To One" relathionship to avoid error
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private User user;

    public Address(String country, String province, String zipCode, String street, String notes, User user) {
        super();
        this.country = country;
        this.province = province;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        this.street = street;
        this.notes = notes;
        this.user = user;
    }
   ```

   }
3. **UserType**: it represents a type of user.

   @Entity
   @Table(name = "user_type")
   @Getter
   @Setter
   public class UserType implements Serializable {

   ```
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6904959949570501298L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "type_name")
    private String typeName;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(
        name = "user_type_operation", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user_type_id") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_operation_id") }
    )
    Set<Operation> operations;


    public UserType() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public UserType(String typeName, String description) {
        super();
        this.typeName = typeName;
        this.description = description;
    }
   ```

   }

**NOTE:** HERE IS WHEERE I FOUND A PROBLEM as you can see this contains this **Many To Many** relationship betwenn **user_type** table (mapped by **UserType) and the **operation** table (mapped by **Operation). This is a many to many relationship because a specific user type can have multiple possible operation and an operation can be related to multiple user types).

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinTable(
    name = "user_type_operation", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user_type_id") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_operation_id") }
)
Set<Operation> operations;
```

The problem is that all the information are saved in my database except this last relationship.

to test it I created this JUnit test method:

```
@SpringBootTest()
@ContextConfiguration(classes = GetUserWsApplication.class)
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
public class UserRepositoryTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository userRepository;
    
    @Autowired 
    UserTypeRepository userTypeRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    OperationRepository operationRepository;
    
    
    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public void testInserAdmintUser() {
        
        //System.out.println(10/0); 
        User user = new User("Luca", null, "Verdi", 'M', new Date(), "XXX", "xxx@gmail.com", "329123456", new Date());
        
        Set<Address> addressesList = new HashSet<>();
        addressesList.add(new Address("Italy", "RM", "00100", "Via XXX 123", "near YYY", user));
        
        user.setAddressesList(addressesList);
        
        List<UserType> userTypesList = userTypeRepository.findAll();
        
        List<Operation> operationsList = operationRepository.findAll();
        Set<Operation> operationSet = new HashSet<Operation>();
        operationSet.add(operationsList.get(0));                        // Constains only ADMIN OPERATION
        
        //Set<UserType> userTypesSet = new HashSet<UserType>(userTypesList);
        Set<UserType> userTypesSet = new HashSet<UserType>();
        
        userTypesList.get(0).setOperations(operationSet);
        
        userTypesSet.add(userTypesList.get(0));                     // Contains only ADMIN user type
        
        user.setUserTypes(userTypesSet);    
        
        userRepository.save(user);
        assertTrue(true);
        
    }
    
}
```

In this method I first set a list of addresses on the **User** instance that is the main object that must be persisted.

Then I set a **UserType** list (at the moment only a specific type related to the **ADMIN** type) and I associate a specific operation to this user type.

Running this method, before persist the object with the **save()** method I inspected the **user** object to be saved with the debugger and I obtained this:

```
user    (id=124)    
    addressesList   HashSet<E>  (id=146)    
    birthdate   Date  (id=148)  
    contactNumber   329123456" (id=151) 
    createdAt   Date  (id=156)  
    eMail   xxx@gmail.com" (id=157) 
    firstName   Luca" (id=158)  
    id  0   
    middleName  null    
    sex M   
    surname Verdi" (id=159) 
    taxCode XXX" (id=160)   
    userTypes   HashSet<E>  (id=131)    
        [0] UserType  (id=143)  
            description Admin user type !!!" (id=164)   
            id  7   
            operations  HashSet<E>  (id=166)    
            typeName    ADMIN" (id=167) 
Add new expression
```

So as you can see it contains all the information including:

- The **userTypes** HashSet: this information will be correctly stored into my **portal_user_user_type** Many To Many relationship table.
- The **userTypes --> operations** HashSet: HERE MY PROBLEM. This information is not stored into **user_type_operation** Many To Many relationship table.

My unit test method doesn't fail. I have no exception. All the information are correctly stored into the DB except the information that represent this **Many To Many** relationship defined into the **UserType** entity class:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinTable(
    name = "user_type_operation", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user_type_id") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_operation_id") }
)
Set<Operation> operations;
```

This is the Hibernate output in my console:

```
USER: com.easydefi.users.entity.User@6e4bccc
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        portal_user
        (birthdate, contact_number, created_at, e_mail, first_name, middle_name, sex, surname, tex_code) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        address
        (country, notes, province, street, fk_user_id, zip_code) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        portal_user_user_type
        (portal_user_id_fk, user_type_id_fk) 
    values
        (?, ?)
```

As you can see it seems that it is performing all the INSERT query except the one that have to insert into the **user_type_operation**

Why? What could be wrong? What am I missing? How can I try to fix this issue in order to fix this problem?

Comment: @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE }) what if you change to CascadeType.ALL ?

Comment: Like with this only the merge operation get propagated, but not save ... I think ...

Comment: I think that CascadeType.ALL  it is not the solution because using this it will also write into the Operation table that is a typological table !!!

Comment: @ArthurKlezovich anyway I tried also to use the CascadeType.ALL but still not perform the INSERT query related to this second level ManyToMany relationship

Comment: Did you change it both on the User and UserType entities ?

Comment: @ArthurKlezovich I confirm you that I cannot use CascateType.ALL on the User because in this way it will add a new record in the typological. It is not the solution